# Set website ID to 1 for all new products

Tags: magento-1.9, product

we have 200 products in our existing Magento website and there are more made in them. Can anyone please let me how we can set the website ID as 1 for all existing as well as new products in Magento?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should go to product grid and `select` all products.

> Actions --> Update Attributes --> Submit --> select tab Websites -->
>   Add Product To Websites box --> tick Main Website check box --> save.

[image]

[image]